# Check the result of a math expression in mysql

Tags: mysql, math, filter, where-clause, evaluation

Let's say I have a table, which has four columns (`a`, `b`, `oper` and `c`) and some primary key column. `oper` means *arithmetic operation* (`+ - * /`) here.

```
a  b  oper  c
-------------
2  3  +     5
4  2  /     3
6  1  *     9
8  5  -     3
```

As, we can see in some cases, `a <oper> b != c`. So, my question is how to filter out such cases?

I've heard of `execute`, which is used for executing statements, but I don't know how to use it inside `where` clause.

Also, I'm not generalizing the `oper` to *any* arithmetic operation, but it would be nice to know, if any function exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM table 
WHERE с != CASE oper WHEN '+' THEN a+b
                     WHEN '-' THEN a-b
                     WHEN '*' THEN a*b
                     WHEN '/' THEN a/b
                     ELSE NULL END
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b99198aa89088cc6584bdc18ffcc8163)

Comment: Thanks, but is there any shorter way to evaluate any general math expression and compare it, maybe some function

Comment: @vrintle MySQL have no EVALUATE-similar function. And dynamic SQL is even more complex.